# How to Convert MySQL Query with Function and View into HQL for Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, spatial

I have a working MySQL query that uses a custom function and a view to perform a spatial calculation. The function `vParameterFunction()` returns a point, and the view `vTestView` calculates the distance between points using the `ST_Distance_Sphere` function.

Here's the MySQL code:

```sql
-- Function to return a point
create function vParameterFunction() returns point
    DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
    return @vParameter;

-- View that calculates distance
create view vTestView as
select Location.*,
       ST_Distance_Sphere(vParameterFunction(), point(Location.lon, Location.lat)) AS Distance
from Location
where Location.lon is not null
  and Location.lat is not null
  and ST_Distance_Sphere(ParameterFunction(), point(Location.lon, Location.lat));
```

I use the following MySQL query to select data from the `vTestView` view:

```sql
select TV.*
from (select @vParameter := point(-105.00862521404056, 39.75709045305179)) parm,
     vTestView TV
where TV.Distance < 10000;
```

Now, I am trying to convert the above MySQL select statement into Hibernate Query Language (HQL) so that I can use it with Hibernate. I have created an entity for vTestView. How can I achieve this conversion, and what would be the equivalent HQL query for this use case?